# After new firmware, can't install ROM (mount error)

Tags: twrp, rom, mount, htc-one-s, lineageos

I installed [RUU 4.2.2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2751518) in an attempt to upgrade HBOOT to 2.16 on a HTC One S. The boot menu shows 2.16 so I guess it worked but now I have no OS.

I am trying to install a ROM (Lineage 14) but I get error messages like this

```
mount: failed to mount /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/
umount of /system failed: no such volume
Patching system image unconditionally...
E1001: Failed to update system image.
E:unknown command[log]
E:Erorr executing updater binary in zip '/sdcard/linea
Error flashing zip '/sdcard/lineage.zip'
Updating partition details...
```

If I `adb shell` then `ls /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1` I get

```
by-num      mmcblk0p13  mmcblk0p19  mmcblk0p24  mmcblk0p3   mmcblk0p35  mmcblk0p8
mmcblk0     mmcblk0p14  mmcblk0p2   mmcblk0p25  mmcblk0p30  mmcblk0p36  mmcblk0p9
mmcblk0p1   mmcblk0p15  mmcblk0p20  mmcblk0p26  mmcblk0p31  mmcblk0p4
mmcblk0p10  mmcblk0p16  mmcblk0p21  mmcblk0p27  mmcblk0p32  mmcblk0p5
mmcblk0p11  mmcblk0p17  mmcblk0p22  mmcblk0p28  mmcblk0p33  mmcblk0p6
mmcblk0p12  mmcblk0p18  mmcblk0p23  mmcblk0p29  mmcblk0p34  mmcblk0p7
```

In TWRP 2.6.1.0 I can wipe cache and Dalvik cache, Format Data and Factory Reset. If I `adb shell` and run `mount` I get

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p34 on /cache type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p35 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p35 on /sdcard type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

I can mount `cache`, `data`, and `system` from the TWRP menu, but not `USB-OTG`.  If I go to Advanced Wipe, I see

```
E:Unable to mount '/usb-otg'
```

How do I fix these errors so I can install my OS?

Comment: It's a lil miraculous that I happen to check SE 10 minutes within you posting all your questions today...

Comment: What exactly did you do with adb shell? I assume you created system directory with ext2,3, or 4 FS. Please help me with exact steps. I'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: I upgraded the TWRP version from 2.7.something to 3.1.something using instructions from https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-twrp/ The problem is solved still interested in the manual solution. do let me know how to get around it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Still assuming S4 variant. Your TWRP is *so* outdated - get the latest [here](https://dl.twrp.me/ville/). Flash through fastboot as usual.

Comment: Not guaranteed to solve, but I think 2.6.x isn't compatible with the new partition layout introduced in HBOOT 2.16 anyway.

Comment: I have TWRP 3, still getting these and similar errors. TWRP "fix partition" tool doesn't work either.

Comment: Tried ROMs with older Android versions? See if the problem's with this particular package.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going into `adb shell` and running `mkdir`, `mount`, and `mke2fs` manually.

Comment: Can you explain how you did? It will help users more.